# is there a way to directly open a terminal in a vertical split in vim?

Tags: vim, terminal, split

Now when I want to open a new terminal in a vertical split I have to open a new window with <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> then I have to enter `:term` and then close the new window that has been splitted with `:term`.
There must be a faster way to do this. A way where I can directly open my terminal in vertical split.

Comment: I've just edited your question, you can look at the edits to see (1) how to show keys and (2) that you don't need 3 backticks for inline code.

Answer (score 5):

You can do `:vert term`, but it isn't that faster, honestly.

On the other hand, you could also do `:term` and then <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> (see `:help CTRL-W_H`).

If pressing <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> bothers you so much, you can try [this plugin](https://github.com/Aster89/WinZoZ) I wrote.